# why Odoo is not shown completely on my server?

Tags: cloud, odoo, vps

This is the error of the vps server:

[image]

The web page of the web program is not shown, or it is incomplete. It is hosted on a vps server and it runs in a docker container that shows ports 8070 and 8071 respectively.

How can I make them visualize correctly?

Is it a problem with the database?

Is it a memory problem or server performance?

**:::: this is my code terraform ::::**

```
terraform {                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  required_version = ">=0.10.6"                                                                                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                

provider "rancher" {                                                                                                                                                                                             
  api_url = "http://144.xxx.xx.xx:8080"                                                                                                                                                                          
  access_key = "FxxxxxxxxxxxxxAF9"                                                                                                                                                                            
  secret_key = "MVxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxeHtG"                                                                                                                                                        
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                

resource "rancher_environment" "production" {                                                                                                                                                                    
  name = "production"                                                                                                                                                                                            
  description = "Production Environment"                                                                                                                                                                         
  orchestration = "cattle"                                                                                                                                                                                       

}                                                                                                                                                                                                                

resource "rancher_environment" "staging" {                                                                                                                                                                       
  name = "stagin"                                                                                                                                                                                                
  description = "Stagin Environment"                                                                                                                                                                             
  orchestration = "kubernetes"                                                                                                                                                                                   

}                                                                                                                                                                                                                

resource "docker_container" "nginx-server" {                                                                                                                                                                     
  name = "nginx-server"                                                                                                                                                                                          
  image = "nginx:latest"                                                                                                                                                                                         
  ports {                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    internal = 80                                                                                                                                                                                                
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  volumes {                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    container_path  = "./nginx.conf"                                                                                                                                                                             
    read_only = true                                                                                                                                                                                             
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                

provider "postgresql" {                                                                                                                                                                                          
  host            = "1xx.xxx.xx.xx"                                                                                                                                                                              
  port            = 5432                                                                                                                                                                                         
  database        = "postgres"                                                                                                                                                                                   
  username        = "odoo"                                                                                                                                                                                       
  password        = "odoo"                                                                                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                

resource "docker_container" "db-storage" {                                                                                                                                                                       
    name = "db-storage"                                                                                                                                                                                          
    image = "busybox"                                                                                                                                                                                            
    volumes= {                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        container_path = "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"                                                                                                                                                       
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    labels =                                                                                                                                                                                                     
     {io.rancher.container.start_once = "true"}                                                                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                

resource "docker_container" "db" {                                                                                                                                                                               
    image = "postgres"                                                                                                                                                                                           
    name = "db"                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    restart = "always"                                                                                                                                                                                           
    hostname = "14x.xxx.xx.xx"                                                                                                                                                                                   
    env = [                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      "production",                                                                                                                                                                                              
      "PGDATA= /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata",                                                                                                                                                                 
      "POSTGRES_DB= odoo_db",                                                                                                                                                                                    
      "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo",                                                                                                                                                                                  
      "POSTGRES_USER=odoo"]                                                                                                                                                                                      
    volumes = {                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        from_container = "db-storage"                                                                                                                                                                            
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    ports = {                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    internal = 5432                                                                                                                                                                                          
    external = 5432                                                                                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    labels=                                                                                                                                                                                                      
     { io.rancher.sidekicks = "db-storage"}                                                                                                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 resource "docker_container" "Odoo-iku" {                                                                                                                                                                         
  name  = "Odoo-iku"                                                                                                                                                                                             
  image = "ikusolutions/odoo-iku:latest"                                                                                                                                                                         
  links = ["db"]                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  ports {                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    external = 8070                                                                                                                                                                                              
    internal = 8069                                                                                                                                                                                              
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  hostname = "iku"                                                                                                                                                                                               
  domainname = "iku.solutions"                                                                                                                                                                                   
  restart = "always"                                                                                                                                                                                             
  env   = ["production",                                                                                                                                                                                         
           "DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR=db",                                                                                                                                                                          
           "DB_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT=5432",                                                                                                                                                                        
            "DB_ENV_POSTGRES_USER=odoo",                                                                                                                                                                         
           "DB_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo"]
```

}

any idea?

thanks...

Comment: Please include the error here, don't just post a link to an image. Thanks and good luck!

Comment: The linked image does not seem to be an error. What is your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your instance is missing web assets in filestore. Your Terraform has persistent storage for Postgres, but is missing storage for Odoo container. Add persistence to your containers for Odoo filestore volume and it will solve this problem.

More information on using Docker persistent storage with Odoo container can be found from this blog post: https://unkkuri.com/blog/unkkuri-blog-1/post/install-odoo-version-11-in-docker-container-21.

Comment: docker network create --driver bridge odoo-nw

    #db container
    docker volume create --name db-data

    docker run -d --name db --env POSTGRES_USER=odoo --env
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD=iku-secret-pw --network=odoo-nw --
   mount source=db-data,target=/var/lib/postgresql/data 
    ikusolutions/postgres:10

    #Odoo container
    docker volume create --name odoo-iku-data

    docker run -d --name odoo-iku --link db:db -p 8070:8069 -- 
    network=odoo-nw --mount source=odoo-iku- 
   data,target=/var/lib/odoo --env POSTGRES_PASSWORD=iku- 
   secret-pw ikusolutions/odoo-iku

Comment: Did you recreate the container and database? The mount in comment seems right to me. Have you tried cleaning browser cache so that you do not have session information still left in browser? You can try this with browser private or incognito window.

Comment: what about kubernetes ?